# Where does 'man 7 undocumented' come from?

Tags: ubuntu, man

On Ubuntu 16.04, I got the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ man 2 chmod
No manual entry for chmod in section 2
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ man 7 undocumented
No manual entry for undocumented in section 7
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$
```

After installing `manpages-dev` (and `ubuntu-docs`) I have the man page for `chmod(2)`.  But, I still don't have the man page for `undocumented(7)`.

What package is supposed to provide this man page?

(This is using the official Xenial 64 Vagrant box.)

Comment: Hmm.... `$ apt-file search man7/undocumented
manpages-es: /usr/share/man/es/man7/undocumented.7.gz
manpages-fr: /usr/share/man/fr/man7/undocumented.7.gz
manpages-pl: /usr/share/man/pl/man7/undocumented.7.gz`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It used to be provided in the `manpages` package, but was [removed in February 2016](https://bugs.debian.org/506653). Debian Policy used to mandate its use for commands with no documentation, but [that’s been obsolete for a long time](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=39830).

There is [an open bug against `man-db`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=32019) related to its referencing `undocumented(7)` (which only happens if the requested manpage matches a command on the user’s `PATH`).